# Entity Framework 6: How to override SQL generator?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, sql-generation

I'd like to amend the SQL that's being generated by EF:CF when generating the database schema (DDL), as [suggested by the Entity Framework team](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2591).

How can this be done?

I couldn't find anything appropriate via Google.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can override the [`MigrationSqlGenerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.sql.migrationsqlgenerator.aspx) that is used by Entity Framework by calling the [DbMigrationsConfiguration.SetSqlGenerator()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration.setsqlgenerator.aspx) method in the constructor of your `DbMigrationsConfiguration` class, passing the database provider name (e.g. `"System.Data.SqlClient"` for SQL Server), and the `MigrationSqlGenerator` instance to use for that database provider.

Consider the example from [the work item](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2591) that you linked to:

```c#
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(5)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose that the table for `MyEntity` had already been generated and the `Add-Migration` command was used to add the `Name` field.

By default, the scaffolded migration is:

```c#
public partial class AddMyEntity_Name : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.MyEntity", "Name", c => c.String(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.MyEntity", "Name");
    }
}
```

Notice that the scaffolder did not generate anything for the `MinLengthAttribute`.

To have EF convey the minimum length requirement, you can [specify an attribute-to-column annotation convention](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Annotations).  As mentioned on that documentation page, any [`AnnotationValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.annotations.annotationvalues.aspx) are ignored by the default SQL generators.

Within your DbContext's OnModelCreating() override, add the following:

```c#
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<MinLengthAttribute, Int32>("minLength", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().Length));
```

After adding that, you can regenerate the scaffolded migration by running `Add-Migration -Force AddMyEntity_Name`.  Now the scaffolded migration is:

```c#
public partial class AddMyEntity_Name : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.MyEntity", "Name", c => c.String(nullable: false,
            annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
            {
                { 
                    "minLength",
                    new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "5")
                },
            }));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.MyEntity", "Name",
            removedAnnotations: new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "minLength", "5" },
            });
    }
}
```

Suppose that, as in the linked work item, you want to generate a constraint to check that the trimmed `Name` value is greater than the minLength (5 in this case).

You can start by creating a custom `MigrationSqlGenerator` that extends `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` and call SetSqlGenerator() to install the custom `MigrationSqlGenerator`:

```c#
internal class CustomSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(AddColumnOperation addColumnOperation)
    {
        base.Generate(addColumnOperation);
    }
}

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

        SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new CustomSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator());
    }

    protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Right now, this `CustomSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator` overrides the Generate(AddColumnOperation) method, but simply calls the base implementation.

If you look at [the documentation of `AddColumnOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.model.addcolumnoperation.aspx), you will see two important properties, `Column` and `Table`.  `Column` is the [`ColumnModel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.model.columnmodel.aspx) that was created by the lambda in Up(), `c => c.String(nullable: false, annotations: ...)`.

In the Generate() method, you can access the custom `AnnotationValues` via the `Annotations` property of the `ColumnModel`.

To generate the DDL that adds the constraint, you need to generate the SQL and call the Statement() method.  For example:

```c#
internal class CustomSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(AddColumnOperation addColumnOperation)
    {
        base.Generate(addColumnOperation);

        var column = addColumnOperation.Column;
        if (column.Type == System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.PrimitiveTypeKind.String)
        {
            var annotations = column.Annotations;
            AnnotationValues minLengthValues;
            if (annotations.TryGetValue("minLength", out minLengthValues))
            {
                var minLength = Convert.ToInt32(minLengthValues.NewValue);
                if (minLength > 0)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToString(column.DefaultValue).Trim().Length < minLength)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("minLength {0} specified for {1}.{2}, but the default value, '{3}', does not satisfy this requirement.", minLength, addColumnOperation.Table, column.Name, column.DefaultValue));
                    }

                    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
                    {
                        writer.Write("ALTER TABLE ");
                        writer.Write(Name(addColumnOperation.Table));
                        writer.Write(" ADD CONSTRAINT ");
                        writer.Write(Quote("ML_" + addColumnOperation.Table + "_" + column.Name));
                        writer.Write(" CHECK (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM({0}))) > {1})", Quote(column.Name), minLength);
                        Statement(writer.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you run `Update-Database -Verbose`, you will see an exception generated by `CustomSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator`:

```
minLength 5 specified for dbo.MyEntity.Name, but the default value, '', does not satisfy this requirement.
```

To fix this issue, specify a defaultValue in the Up() method that is longer than the minimum length (e.g. `"unknown"`):

```c#
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.MyEntity", "Name", c => c.String(nullable: false, defaultValue: "unknown",
            annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues>
            {
                { 
                    "minLength",
                    new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "5")
                },
            }));
    }
```

Now if you re-run `Update-Database -Verbose`, you will see the `ALTER TABLE` statement that adds the column and the `ALTER TABLE` statement that adds the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyEntity] ADD [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyEntity] ADD CONSTRAINT [ML_dbo.MyEntity_Name] CHECK (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM([Name]))) > 5)
```

See also: [EF6: Writing Your Own Code First Migration Operations](http://romiller.com/2013/02/27/ef6-writing-your-own-code-first-migration-operations/), which shows how to implement a custom migration operation.

Comment: Thanks for this, helped me to understand what is wrong with Oracles dam Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.OracleMigrationSqlGenerator which errors on any Annotation in migrations.