# Entity Framework 6 Code first Default value overriding the MigrationCodeGenerator

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, default-value, entity-framework-migrations

All the approaches I've found about declaring default values, generates the default value in the Sql script, not in the migration code.

My favorite is using attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34894274/132942

```
[SqlDefaultValue(DefaultValue = "getutcdate()")]
public DateTime CreatedDateUtc { get; set; }
```

## Attribute definition

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SqlDefaultValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

## In the "OnModelCreating" of the context adding

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add( new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<SqlDefaultValueAttribute, string>("SqlDefaultValue", (p, attributes) => attributes.Single().DefaultValue));
```

And then customizing the **SqlGenerator**. But I don't like this because I don't see when generating the migration if everything it's as I wanted.

To do so, I modified the **MigrationCodeGenerator** like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21024108

## In the custom MigrationCodeGenerator

```
public class ExtendedMigrationCodeGenerator : MigrationCodeGenerator
{
    public override ScaffoldedMigration Generate(string migrationId, IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> operations, string sourceModel, string targetModel, string @namespace, string className)
    {
        foreach (MigrationOperation operation in operations)
        {
            if (operation is CreateTableOperation)
            {
                foreach (var column in ((CreateTableOperation)operation).Columns)
                {
                    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Annotations.AnnotationValues values;
                    if (column.Annotations.TryGetValue("SqlDefaultValue", out values))
                    {
                        column.DefaultValueSql = (string)values.NewValue;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (operation is AddColumnOperation)
            {
                ColumnModel column = ((AddColumnOperation)operation).Column;

                System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Annotations.AnnotationValues values;
                if (column.Annotations.TryGetValue("SqlDefaultValue", out values))
                {
                    column.DefaultValueSql = (string)values.NewValue;
                }

            }
        }

        CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator generator = new CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator();

        return generator.Generate(migrationId, operations, sourceModel, targetModel, @namespace, className);
    }
}
```

But in the method **ScaffoldedMigration** I cannot get my custom annotation **SqlDefaultValue** or any other annotation.

Is it possible to get this annotation?

Comment: The code you posted works as expected (I'm getting `CreatedDateUtc = c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "getutcdate()")` inside `CreateTable` call in the migration). Are you sure your custom migration code generator is called at all? e.g. the line in the `Configuration` class which sets it as `CodeGenerator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't indicated how you *registered* your `ExtendedMigrationCodeGenerator` to be used, you can do this in the constructor of the `Configuration` class in `Configuration.cs` for example:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    // Register the Customized Migration Generator to use
    CodeGenerator = new ExtendedMigrationCodeGenerator();
}
```

But also do not forget the `AlterColumnOperation` which might be your biggest issue if you are applying this to an existing schema.

```
else if (operation is AlterColumnOperation alterColumnOp)
{
    ColumnModel column = alterColumnOp.Column;

    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Annotations.AnnotationValues values;
    if (column.Annotations.TryGetValue("SqlDefaultValue", out values))
    {
        column.DefaultValueSql = (string)values.NewValue;
    }
}
```

The other scenario where you will not see a generated output is if the convention and annotations were already applied in a previous migration that was generated *before* you configured the custom `ExtendedMigrationCodeGenerator`.

### Debugging tip:

Debugging custom migration logic isn't as simple as setting a breakpoint, because it is normally executed by external processes like `Migration.exe`. So before breakpoints will work, we need to invoke the debugger, we can do this by inserting the following code either at the point where you want to debug or in the constructor of the migration code generator class:

```
if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

> It is better to attach in a constructor rather than near the code you want to debug because we know the constructor should be executed under normal conditions, but the reason your code isn't working might be due to the method or code branch not being executed at all, if it's not being executed, then the `Launch()` command also will not be executed.

If you use this method to debug the migration and you don't get the debug attach dialog then either there are no migrations detected, or your `ExtendedMigrationCodeGenerator` hasn't been registered correctly.